# Automatic conversion between .ps to .pdf upon download onto Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, automator, pdf, postscript

Is there any way to convert `.ps` to `.pdf` every time automatically as a `.ps` is downloaded onto a Mac machine? (Using Mountain Lion 10.8)

- can Automator perform this task?
- convert and then delete the `.ps`

It's annoying that it has to convert from `.ps` to `.pdf` in preview every time I open the file, and quick preview doesn't work on `.ps`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Folder Action for that.

Right click on to your download folder

select Folder Action Set up:

Choose Covert PostScript to pdf action.

done

If you feel like modifying the script go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up Acrobat Distiller with a watched folder, or use Automator with it. This gives you better control over the conversion options, as you could specify the .joboptions.